# How to Target DOM elements in v-for

Tags: vue.js, v-for

**Context:** I create a little social network to discover vue.js.
On the timeline page, I have posts and comments (the problem are the comments)

Actually, I display all comments, and I NOW I want with the button <kbd>Hidecomments</kbd> to let display only the two last comments and hide all others.

I want to use a CSS class to hide them.

I am unable to execute a function in an 'entry scope' and I don't find any information about that point in the documentation.

**Code:**

First point: I have an API which sends me the information.

```js
module.exports = {
  data: function() {
    return {
      timeline: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    displayMoreComments: function() {

    }
  },

  mounted() {
    let self = this;
    fetch(test.ajax_url + '/get_timeline', {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
          'dataType': 'json',
          'type': 'post'
        }
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        self.timeline = data;
      });
  },
}
```

```html
<div v-for="entry in timeline.entries">
  <div :key="entry.id">
    <p>{{ entry.content }}</p>
    <button v:on:click="HideComments()"></button>
    <div v-for="comments in entry.comments">
      <p>{{ comments.content}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Question:** What is the best way to modify comments when I click on the button <kbd>hideComments</kbd> and display only the two lasts comments.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it, but this should work.

Add a variable in your vue data to manage comments visibility.

```js
data: function() {
    return {
        noComments: false;
    }
},
```

then set the button to toggle visibility

```html
<button v:on:click="noComments = !noComments"></button>
```

and, at the end, use v-if to check the new variable's value. If comments are hidden just check if the current comment is one of the last two

```html
<div v-if="!noComments || entry.comments.length == index + 1 || entry.comments.length == index" 
     v-for="(comments,index) in entry.comments">
    <p>{{ comments.content}}</p>
</div>
```

IMPORTANT: remember to add index in v-for